# Python program to do NLTK download stop-words without GUI acting as blocker

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

I am trying to write a simple python program to download stop-words but everytime a GUI pops up. I do not want any manual interference that someone clicks on the GUI to dispose it off, instead the download should be automatic.

import nltk 
nltk.download('all')

Comment: read docs first. when you run nltk.download new window should open, you will download ALL once, i don't get it why this should be a problem at all?

Comment: https://www.nltk.org/data.html

Comment: Once downloaded, nltk_data size is around 35 mb and I cannot package it along with my source code and deploy to clients infrastructure because overall size of my build is breaching certain threshold.So I want this download to happen at clientsite without any manual intervention.The GUI pop up is a blocking call so nothing happens unless one clicks on it and there is nobody to click on it in production environment.